# How do I show dates in UK format in an Excel when viewed in a browser?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, sharepoint

We have a sheet on SharePoint for Daily Standup notes. If I open the document in my browser, the date format is mm/dd/yyyy (incorrect). If I open in the desktop application, the dates show as dd/mm/yyyy (correct).

Browser-based view:

[image]

In Excel desktop application

[image]

My Account shows that my regional settings are UK as expected.

[image]

How do I have Excel browser viewer show the correct date format?

Comment: are your browser and online Excel set correctly to use English (UK)?

Comment: Chrome has no date or region preferences, I assume they inherit from the OS.

Comment: Excel saves the dates in an agnostic format, so the application on the other end decides how to display them. You can have a look here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-regional-format-settings-in-excel-for-the-web-c206344b-0d45-4a82-8eee-34ff6b008e9c how to change it in the online viewer. It seems that it inherits the regional settings not from your own OS, but from the SharePoint server by default, so that's probably the problem.

Comment: @spikey_richie of course Chrome has a language settings like any other browsers https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop

Comment: @phuclv I didn't say anything about language. I said date or region preferences. They're different things.

Comment: @spikey_richie of course I know that. But websites typically use the locale taken from the language setting in the browser

Comment: `English (United Kingdom)` at the top, `English (United States)` second.

Comment: https://office-watch.com/2014/excel-online-changing-date-format/ Is this article helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the file open in the online app, go to `File` > `Options`

[image]

And then `Regional format settings` and check that is set to "English (United Kingdom)".

[image]

If you change this then the file should re-load and display correctly.

Comment: If I click the `Settings` button in Chrome, it takes me to the My Account page which I have included in my question.

Comment: And what happens when you go to File > options in the Excel file itself, opened in the app? This is not a Chrome setting, and not a global setting for your Office 365 account, it is file-specific as far as I know (having seen similar issues myself previously).

Comment: Excel desktop application is fine, it's the web-based view that's wrong.

Comment: @spikey_richie He means go to File/Options on the Excel Online spreadsheet in your browser, not the downloaded desktop app

Comment: That got it, thanks. Answer updated with screenshots too.